# WebStorm 10.0.3 ignoring typescript breakpoints

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, webstorm, source-maps

WebStorm 10.0.3 does not pause at typescript breakpoints.
This has worked for me before using WebStorm 9.

Note:
I know that the generated source maps are ok, because chrome dev tools manages to pause on breakpoints in .ts (typescript) files.

Any ideas?

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: Looks like a ticket to me.

Comment: @Knu Could be, Opened a ticket.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16829

Comment: Chrome version? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16645 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chrome v43?

If so -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16645 -- that's the ticket for the issue with explanations.

You can either:

- Downgrade to Chrome v42
- Use custom build of WebStorm v10.0.3 (links are listed in [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16645#comment=27-1005430))
- WebStorm v10.0.4 should also contain the fix (not yet publicly available).

Comment: Thanks! that discussion contains a fixed version (tested it myself), although it seems that it takes time for the debugger to attach, because only breakpoints after window load or setTimeout are caught, other "too soon" breakpoints are still ignored, updated my issue/ticket at jetbrains.